# Unexpected element 'resource-ref' encountered while migrating from java1.5 to java1.8

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x

I am migrating an old application running on java 1.5 and jboss 4.3 to java 1.8 and jboss 7.2. While deploying on jboss 7.2, I am getting error related to resource-ref defined under ejb-ref in jboss-web.xml.

I was able to transform other parts of the application like moving libraries to modules and changes in EJB lookup jndi however I am not able to find a solution to make resource-ref work with ejb-ref

```
<jboss-web>
     ... 
     <ejb-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/CA_ProductEJBHome</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-link>ProductEJB.jar#CA_ProductEJB</ejb-link>
        <jndi-name>CA_ProductEJB</jndi-name>
        <resource-ref>
            <description>Product Database</description>
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/productDB</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/CA_productDB</jndi-name>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
    </ejb-ref> 
    ...
</jboss-web>
```

Error Trace :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[127,3]
Message: Unexpected element 'resource-ref' encountered
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:115)
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.ee.EJBReferenceMetaDataParser.parse(EJBReferenceMetaDataParser.java:90)
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.ee.EnvironmentRefsGroupMetaDataParser.parseRemote(EnvironmentRefsGroupMetaDataParser.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question. 
Issue below:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[127,3]
Message: Unexpected element 'resource-ref' encountered
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:115)
```

So in for EAP 6/7 we needed to modify the JNDI names, following a name convention.

### JNDI name convention

Following the migration guide in 3.2.14.2.3. Application Changes Required to Run EJB 2.x
  We go to: Modify the JBoss-web.xml File Descriptor, which describes that you must modify the  for each  for 'new JNDI fully qualified' lookup format: either java:global, or java:module, or java:app.

### Exception

My guess is that the parser, while reading the  tag, was expecting this standard and since it didn't find the exception was thrown. Pay attention also on the parenting since  is at the same level as

Regards